# How to use CSVReader?

Tags: java, csv, inputstream, fileinputstream

I'm trying to read my file in notepad using `CSVReader` but I  cannot get it work. it says `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 line "y[i][2]".` eventhough I intiallize my array rows in 100. I'm currently new in using Java and CSVReader.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    double[][] x = new double[100][3];
    double[][] y = new double[100][1];

    String line[];
    try{
        CSVReader br=new CSVReader(new FileReader("ex2data2.txt"),',');
        int i = 0;
        while((line=br.readNext())!=null){
            x[i][0] = Double.parseDouble(line[0]);
            x[i][1] = Double.parseDouble(line[1]);
            y[i][2] = Double.parseDouble(line[2]);
            i++;
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Um, your `y` 2d array allows for exactly one element in the second level array, and you are trying to store something at the third.

Comment: You don't need something as complex as CVSReader to read a simple text file... you should also learn Java before trying to get into the more advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely unclear as to *why* you would be storing the data as you are after reading it from the file, but ...

```
double[][] y = new double[100][1];
```

This allocates an array of 100 `double` arrays, each with a length of **1**

Here:

```
 y[i][2] = Double.parseDouble(line[2]);
```

You attempt to store something at the **third** element of one of those 100 arrays. They aren't that large; you created them to have a length of **one**.

I suspect you meant to do:

```
 y[i][0] = Double.parseDouble(line[2]);
```

since the only thing you're storing in the `y` arrays is that single value.

All that being said, this is a poor way to store these values. In general you are better served using a dynamic data structure so you don't have to worry about what the length (number of lines) of the file is. In addition, why would you need two different 2D arrays?  Even a `List<Double[]>`, for example, would be better.

Comment: because I will later store it in my matrix object"Matrix Ax = new matrix(x) where x must be a 2dimensional array (JAMA lib)"how dynamic data structure work? I don't know how to use List<Double[]>

Answer (score 0):

You have create

```
double[][] y = new double[100][1];
```

i.e. 100 rows and 1 column. but trying to put value at position `y[i][2]`. thats why  you are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. create like

```
double[][] y = new double[100][3];
```

or you can simply put value as (in this case you don't need to create 2D array given as above)

```
y[i][0] = Double.parseDouble(line[2]);
```

Comment: You have an off by one error ;) Plus, my ESP is telling me that what the OP *meant* to do was store the value at `y[i][0]`